# To what extent Laravel uses composer?

Tags: laravel

I try to run Laravel on a server that doesn't provide composer. I am aware of these issues which I've resolved:

1) Problem: installing the framework

Solution: installed on local machine and copied files over.

2) Problem: installing packages

Solution: installed them mannually by adding files and modifying autoloader files.

3) Problem: creating and rolling back migrations via artisan

Solution: not found yet. Probably new classes need to be manually added in composer autoloader file.

Is there any more tasks where composer is necessary? I'd like to know to what extent the framework really relies on in before starting development.

Comment: Do you have command line access to your server?

Can't you install composer by simply running curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php?

Comment: @Gravy I'm not sure how reliable composer.phar is. On my installation it produces some errors and warnings so I can't depend on it. Standard installation works fine though on my local server.

Comment: composer.phar is very reliable. Server's don't typically provide composer out of the box. You need to install it. You install it by downloading the phar.

Comment: Shouldn't really have a problem as long as you follow steps 1 and 2 and for step 3 you will just have to use phpMyAdmin or some other db tool to manually updated/create tables